# what is the difference between string_variable and CStr(string_variable)

Tags: string, vba

I have a piece of Excel-VBA code of which the following behavior escapes my understanding

```
option explicit

....

private sub XYZ() 

   dim s       as string
   dim ser     as series
   dim diagram as chart

   ...

   s = function_returning_string(....)

 ' Following line throws runtime exception 13 
   set ser = diagram.seriesCollection.item(s)

   ....

end sub
```

If I try to get a named item in the `seriesCollection` of the `chart` object as outlined above, it throws (the german) errors **laufzeitfehler '13' typen unverträglich** which would be *Run-time error 13: Type mismatch* in english.

Changing the offending line to

```
set ser = diagram.seriesCollection.item(CStr(s))
```

makes to error go away.

I have no idea why that is. `CStr()` is supposed to convert something (here: `s`) into a string, but `s` is *already* a string.

Answer (score 0):

CStr converts the type of a variable into a String data type.

If you have a function s = function_returning_string(....) where s is already typed a string, doing for example this:

```
dim s as string
dim sString as string

sString = cstr(s)
```

would be meaningless.
In other cases, this may be useful.
Sometimes people use it for example to convert a string to a date, using cDate. 
Or to take string, cut off some parts and use cDbl or cInt to convert towards a Double or Integer datatype.

Check your function "function_returning_string" if it is defined as :

```
Public Function function_returning_string() as string
```

In this case, the seriesCollection only allows String typed variables to be added in the collection.

Comment: I didn't carefull read you last phrase, therefore I was too quick and posted too much information. Well, I'll just leave it there. But I don't see a problem either -> It should work if you are certain that the function returns a string. But it doesn't hurt to use cStr, if it helps.

Comment: Just as an additional info: if you want to check the type of a variable, you can use debug.print typename(variable).